# rootpy installation probleme : Is ROOT installed with PyROOT enabled?

Tags: python, pyroot

I have a big problem to install `rootpy`. When I try this command:

```
sudo pip install rootpy
```

I have this error message:

> ROOT cannot be imported. Is ROOT installed with PyROOT enabled?
>   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-OIZeCG/rootpy/

I already have ROOT Version 5.34/30, python 2.7 and python 3.5.

I confirm there is python in the list given by:

```
root-config --features
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install `libroot-bindings-python-dev` package
with

```
sudo apt-get install libroot-bindings-python-dev
```

before installing `rootpy` module.